# Why does the code not work correctly (parser phpQuery)?

Tags: php, phpquery

I do not understand why it does not work. script does not parse the link from the **scr=""**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once 'phpQuery.php';

function parser($url, $start, $end){
 if($start < $end){
  $file = file_get_contents($url);
  $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);
  foreach($doc->find('.video-js') as $article){
 $article = pq($article);

 $scr = $article->find('video')->attr('src');

 echo "<video src='$scr'></video>";
 echo '<hr>';
  }

  $next = $doc->find('.pages-nav .current')->next()->attr('src');
  if( !empty($next) ){
 $start++;
 parser($next, $start, $end);
  }
 }
}

$url = 'http://video.meta.ua/9879129.video';
$start = 0;
$end = 1;
parser($url, $start, $end);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Help please, in what there can be a problem?
what am I doing wrong?..

Comment: For one, you're calling `header()` after you've already sent HTML. That's going to result in an error. I'm also not seeing `pq()` defined anywhere.

Comment: You're mixing `src` and `scr`, although it looks like it's still valid, but might  be a mixup in the original doc. Also, when trying to find the element with the lookup `.pages-nav .current`, there is none. Can you make sure that the `$doc->find(...)` function even finds something?

Comment: The `video` tag doesn't have a `src` attribute (looking at the source code for http://video.meta.ua/9879129.video), at least not on load. It may be populated by JS, in which case you'll need to use another way.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!